# SQL selecting unique key field with most recent date/time

Tags: sql-server, unique

I have a table in my SQL Server DB that contains a list of energy Meter's along with their reading and a date/time stamp.

The basic schema is a PointID column, a Date/Time column and a Value column. The point ID is the key and as such the table contains multiple entries for each PointID with the half hourly value and timestamp.

```
For example:

PointID, Time, Value

132237      2015-06-19 22:00:00.000 46
132237      2015-06-19 22:15:00.000 52
132237      2015-06-19 22:30:00.000 64
154433      2015-06-19 22:45:00.000 41
154433      2015-06-19 23:00:00.000 44
154433      2015-06-19 23:15:00.000 45
154433      2015-06-19 23:30:00.000 47
```

I am trying to write a query to select the most recent row from each unique PointID but am having trouble doing this efficiently without having to select the whole DB, order by desc and limiting by 1.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` in SQL to get that.

```
SELECT POINTID,MAX(VALUE)
FROM table
GROUP BY POINTID
```

Comment: This is the answer we were all expecting to see.

Comment: Thanks that works, however my value column comes back with 'no column name'. I also want to list the timestamp as well against the values but adding my date/time column to the select statement results in the following error:

"Column 'i96X.dbo.PointValue.DataTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: The following returns the time as well. However is this the best way to do this? Getting the max value of two separate columns? Also my column names are still missing.


SELECT PointID, MAX(DataTime), MAX(DataValue)
FROM i96X.dbo.PointValue
GROUP BY PointID

Comment: I don't understand how column names can be missing?

Comment: Nevermind, I have sorted that out by adding 'as 'name here' behind the select statements. But is doing a max aggregate function on two columns in order to get them both in the results acceptable?

With the two columns as max, which one is it using to pull the most recent entry? Timestamp and a number value arent comparable so what happens here?

Comment: @tomstephens89 what you have done is applied an "alias" to the result displayed in your column. SQL Server doesn't know how to call the column, which is why in most cases it is good practice to specify a column name for the result.

Comment: Thanks guys, Ive got this sorted now. For my application that this query is being used in, I didnt need to grab the time field anyway. Just the PointID and the Value columns work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT PointID, Time, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITITION BY PointID ORDER BY Time DESC) AS RN
FROM <YOUR TABLE>
)
SELECT PointID, Time, Value
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Off the top of my head - something like this should work if using SQL Server 2005 or above.